# PostgreSQl: select multiple rows and make it in one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'm using PostgreSQl and this is my table in database:
[image]

how can I write a query that gives me this result :
[image]

Comment: This is a cube, check the manual how to use it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/cube.html

Answer (score 0):

or you can write query like

```
select id_salarie, 
max(case when date_pointage = '2015-01-01' then round(nb_heures::numeric,2) else null end) as "2015-01-01",
max(case when date_pointage = '2015-01-02' then round(nb_heures::numeric,2) else null end)as "2015-01-02", 
max(case when date_pointage = '2015-01-03' then round(nb_heures::numeric,2) else null end) as "2015-01-03"
from my_table where id_salarie = 1
group by id_salarie;
```

Query looks huge and terrible but works for cubes

Comment: Thnx for your answer but this is not helping because the field "date_pointage" is unkown. In this example I chose 7 days but actualy it's unkown, it can be only 4 days or 8 that's the problem.

Comment: you can select date_pointage into cursor and then generate sql-query string and execute it